# Delphi Generics: Can array types be used as type constraints?

Tags: delphi, generics, dynamic-arrays

I have the following code that doesn't compile, and I can't find an explanation as to why.

```
TIndexArray<TType> = array of TType;

TIndexList<TArrayType; TType: TIndexArray<TArrayType>> = class
end;
```

It says the

> Type 'TIndexArray' is not a valid constraint.

But if TIndexArray is a class and not an array type it works.

Comment: You don't really need `TType` in your class declaration. You can just use  `TIndexArray<TArrayType>` directly in your class, or declare `TType = TIndexArray<TArrayType>` within the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array types are not supported as constraints. This is documented behavior:

https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Constraints_in_Generics

> Constraint items include:
>
> - Zero, one, or multiple interface types
> - Zero or one class type
> - The reserved word "constructor", "class", or "record"

No mention of array types.